# Require root password when executing "sudo -s"

Tags: centos, ssh, security, centos7, sudo

I have a CentOS 7 server on AWS.

When logged in with the `centos` user, how can I prevent `sudo -s` logging in to `root` without requiring `root`'s password?

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep rootpw
Defaults rootpw
[root@server ~]# getent group wheel
wheel:x:10:centos
[root@server ~]# gpasswd -d centos wheel
Removing user centos from group wheel
[root@server ~]# getent group wheel
wheel:x:10:
[root@server ~]# su centos
[centos@server root]$ sudo -s
[root@server ~]# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: If you want them to have to know roots password instead of their own, then use su instead of sudo.

Comment: @NiKiZe - so if I have a window at my home that doesn't close, and want to prevent intruders from entering my house, what I do is tell them to use the door, which is locked, rather than fixing the broken window? I want to prevent `sudo -s` from allowing to be root without requiring root's password!

Comment: Then don't allow sudo at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.

The problem is in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`:

```
centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This allows the user `centos` sudo without password.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` always uses the user account's password. If user has `sudo` privileges, then the user can execute commands as root, after entering his own password in the `sudo` prompt.

In your example, you are seeing the effects of `sudo` ticket validity period. Once `sudo` is run for the first time, it asks for a password. After that, it creates a ticket that is valid for a certain time. During this time, `sudo` does not ask for password.

If you want to change this behavior, you can disable the ticket by adding

```
Defaults     timestamp_timeout=0
```

to `/etc/sudoers` configuration file.

Comment: Thank you. I edited `/etc/sudoers` to add `Defaults timestamp_timeout=0`, and tried the `sudo -s` command again as yesterday, and still the same. This only happens with the `centos` user. Other users are asked for the `root` password.

Comment: Then it is likely due to the fact that you are first root, then using `su` to change user and then `sudo`ing. Maybe some user status is remembered after `su`.

Comment: Doesn't happen with other users, though. Only `centos`. Also, if I go directly from AWS's shell (which logs in directly to `centos`, the same happens.